# proxy pass configuration in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am a front end developer and tried my hands in nginx configuration last time which is working fine. The below is the configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
    location / {
             #By default route to node.js running on localhost:9000 port
             proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    #currently only one server but will have to redirect to n hosts based on a parameter
    location /hosts.json {
      proxy_pass      http://app-host.net:3000;
    }
    #currently only one server but will have to redirect to n hosts based on a parameter
    location /hosts/ {
      proxy_pass      http://app-host.net:3000;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to redirect to 4 different servers based on a parameter. ie if the city is `Bangalore`, I need to redirect to `bangalore.corp.net:3000` and if the city is `NewYork`, then I need to redirect to `newyork.corp.net:3000` and so on.

Here is somewhat I am expecting:

```
location /app1/hosts/ {
      proxy_pass      http://app1-host.net:3000;
    }
#But the proxy pass should point to http://app1-host.net:3000/hosts and not http://app1-host.net:3000/app1/hosts
```

How can we handle such proxy pass in the nginx configuration file. Please let me know.

Comment: If you are looking for a conditional rewrite based on the value of a parameter, you might be able to adapt this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/488444/nginx-rewrite-convert-querystring-to-path

Comment: Will it be a proxy-pass or redirect. I want to have proxy-pass and not the redirect

Comment: `rewrite` can do either, see optional `[flag]` parameter: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: You state that you need to redirect based on a parameter. Can you update your question with a specific example. I am not clear on whether the parameter is part of the query element of the URI, and if so, why you cannot use the path element instead. Obviously using the path element (which `nginx` calls the location) would be most efficient.

Comment: @RichardSmith From the above configuration that I have shared, I need to proxy pass to 4 different app servers for a particular request. Say for `/hosts` I would like to call any one of the 4 app servers `proxy-pass  http://app1-host.net:3000; http://app2-host.net:3000; http://app3-host.net:3000; http://app4-host.net:3000;` This should be based on a param that I will be passing. say `/app1/hosts` then it should proxy pass to http://app1-host.net:3000;ope I am clear. Also edited the question by adding more details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a URL of the form `/app1/hosts/foo` which should map to `http://app1-host.net:3000/hosts/foo`. The can be achieved by appending a URI in the `proxy_pass` directive, which will act like an `alias`.

```
location /app1/hosts/ {
  proxy_pass http://app1-host.net:3000/hosts/;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.